# How does a taylor series of a binomial function equals a trigonometric function?

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions, trigonometry, taylor-expansion

[image: Here's what i want to know,how does sinx and cosx equals such taylor series?]

Any proof or derivation for the sinx and cosx function would be help.
Image taken from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series

Comment: Calculate the derivatives of $\;\sin x\,,\,\cos x\,\;$ etc., evaluate in zero and...voila!

Comment: **Hint**: $\sin'(x) = \cos(x), \cos'(x) = -\sin(x)$. Use Taaylor's theorem for the rest.

Comment: You can find the derivations in any college-level analysis textbook.

Comment: ..."in any analysis textbook..." and in hundreds, or thousands, of internet sites.

Comment: You might find [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1103/409) illuminating. It shows the geometric nature of the terms of the power series. (The linked note of mine has a reference to a combinatorial proof for sine and cosine; the note itself covers a slightly-more-involved combinatorial proof for secant and tangent.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find proofs in this [book](http://www.math.binghamton.edu/dennis/478.f07/EleAna.pdf). (chapter 6 for $\tan(x)$ and $\sec(x)$).
For $\sin(x)$ and $\cos(x)$ you must use Taylor theorem.

Comment: So: the advice becomes... after you see some Taylor series given on the internet, and become curious: Go to a textbook (or course) and learn enough calculus to discover what Taylor's theorem says.