# History of infinite series representations of $\sin(x)$ and $\cos(x)$

Tags: math-history, trigonometric-series

When did the famous infinite series representations for $\sin(x)$ and $\cos(x)$ came about?

To be specific when did people realise that the ratio of the two sides of a right triangle with one angle being the size of $x$ radians can be expressed as a sum of an infinite number  of quantities that depend on $x$.

What was the explanation/justification for them? Is there any nice geometric way of seeing that those identities are in fact true?

Comment: The first question (history of the infinite series) is *very* different from the last (geometric visualization). They should be two different questions. (And the second one has almost certainly been asked a few hundred times on this site before.)

Comment: The the first written record of the series representations of trigonometric functions comes from the Indian mathematician [Madhava](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Madhava_series#Madhava.27s_sine_series) in the 1300's.

Comment: James Gregory (1638-1675) is generally credited with discovering the infinite series representations for some of the trig functions (by extension of Archimedes' "method of exhaustion", no less).  Brook Taylor (1685-1731) would not be far behind in advancing this approach.

Comment: OK, I see my sources are again too Eurocentric; I should have figured that if infinities were involved, someone in India had already been thinking about this.  Thanks for the historical pointer!

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to be certain, but close relatives of the series for sine and cosine were probably first obtained by [Madhava](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Madhava_of_Sangamagrama) (1340-1425) of the Kerala school. This work, and related work by other mathematicians of the Kerala school, predated European work on series by more than two centuries.

For a condensed technical discussion, please see the first chapter of Ranjan Roy's wonderful *Sources in the Development of Mathematics: Series and Products from the Fifteenth to the Twenty-first Century.*

Comment: Nice one.  I have a question for you that is not related to this.  If two bernoulli trials go through to infinity and that you want the probability that one of them has more successes than the other at all time, can you use ratio of expected number of successes of one in the numerator and sum of expected number of successes of  both of them in the denominator to arrive at the probability that one will stay ahead in the number of successes than the other.

Comment: I think so, my guess is that it can be done by a variant of the gambler's ruin analysis. Have not done the calculation, however.

Comment: Thanks.  If you happen to solve this for anyone, let me know.

Comment: You should ask it as a question, preferably at a time when the site has a fair bit of activity. Someone will answer.

Comment: No problem, I will do so. I solved a similar problem this way and was kind of quickly verify if it is OK.

Answer (score 1):

The power series for sine and cosine are certainly already in [Euler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leonhard_Euler) if not earlier. He obtained them from the power series for the exponential function. His approach used the binomial formula for an infinite exponent. Euler used both infinite numbers and infinitesimals to obtain correct series developments.

Comment: Where can I read about that?

Answer (score 0):

[This answer of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1103/409) describes a geometric interpretation of the series for sine and cosine, discovered by math teacher Y. S. Chaikovsky at least as early as 1935. The result was presented in [this American Mathematical Monthly article](http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.2307/2974881?uid=3739920&uid=2&uid=4&uid=3739256&sid=21104045780693) in 1996 by Chaikovsky's student, Leo Gurin.