# How do geometric properties of sine and cosine follow from their power series definition?

Tags: calculus, analysis, trigonometry, power-series

If you define $\cos$ and $\sin$ using their power series, or as the real and imaginary part of the power series of $e^{ix}$, how can you prove that they are periodic? Also, how do you prove that period is $\pi$? And how do you prove that the points $(\cos(x), \ \sin(x))$ for $x \in [0, 2\pi]$ form a circle?

I believe the last question can be proven if you use the continuity of $\cos$ and $\sin$, which follows from their power series definition, and from the fact that $\cos^2(x) + \sin^2(x) = 1$, but using only these two properties is not enough for proving they form a full circle I believe. I think you also need to find their derivatives on the intervals $[0, \ \pi/2]$, $[\pi/2, \ \pi]$, $[\pi, \ 3\pi/2]$ and $[3\pi/2, \ 2\pi]$, is this correct? If so, how can this be done?

Comment: The reverse question is asked here: ["Deriving the power series for cosine, using basic geometry"](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2758418/409). You may find [my answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2758743/409) interesting.

Comment: @Blue thank you, but I can't quite follow the proof in that answer, especially since the combinatorial argument is omitted. I appreciate the reference and will probably return to it when my math skills are stronger, but for now I'd appreciate a proof in the direction I asked.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How to prove periodicity of $\sin(x)$ and $\cos(x)$ starting from the Taylor seires expansion?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/63102/how-to-prove-periodicity-of-sinx-or-cosx-starting-from-the-taylor-seri?rq=1)

Comment: Also related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1048/different-definitions-of-trigonometric-functions

Answer (score 1):

wrt "how do you prove that the points (cos(), sin()) for ∈[0,2] form a circle?" see https://gowers.wordpress.com/2014/03/02/how-do-the-power-series-definitions-of-sin-and-cos-relate-to-their-geometrical-interpretations/. wrt earlier questions see the prologue, the exponential function, in Rudin's book *Real and Complex Analysis*. For an elementary discussion of the exponential function see http://math.mit.edu/~gs/calculus/Article_Exponential.pdf