# What is a coordinate free definition of sine?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

Iv always wondered how a sine is computed and related fundamentally to geometry and how it is even defined. Iv seen that mostly this is done with things like COORDINC or something, some coordinate based algorithm, and arc lenght is computed with Cartesian coordinates. I want a

COORDINATE FREE = WITHOUT ANY COORDINATES geometric definition incorporating also the differential equation definition. The input of sine does not need to be x coordinate, it could be an angle, a vector or santa clause as long as its defined corrrectly

Basically sine has second derivative equal to its negative, as does the cosine, in addition to cosine being derivative of sine.  the solutions to these diff equations are the respective trig series. So how does this even prove sin of pi is 0, what is even the definition of pi, and how does all this realise itself in geometry, and by geometry don't mean coordinate systems which are opposite to geometry. (when someone asks about a geometric definition of something usually this means coordinate free

Comment: The sine of an angle was known since antiquity. I suppose then you mean the sine FUNCTION or how the values of that function are computed (which is a different issue): you should explain that more clearly.

Comment: How was it known, they didn't know calculus how did they calculate sine?

Comment: They knew geometry and algebra, and that was more than enough: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Madhava%27s_sine_table

Comment: This is interesting

Answer (score 2):

I had asked a similar question to this on this site, in that I wanted to formalise the definition of cosine starting from the geometric intuition. [Here it is](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3060125/defining-the-cosine-function-from-first-principles-intuitively).

In a sense, you do more or less need coordinates to define the sine and cosine functions, because by definition, they are the length of the sides of the right-angled triangle formed by traveling a distance $\theta$ from a starting point. To have all these notions defined in a "coordinate-free" setting (like Hilbert's axioms for geometry) is a bit of overkill.

Take a look at [these](https://drmenguin.com/files/trig.pdf) (partially completed) [notes](https://drmenguin.com/files/trig.pdf) on trigonometry, where I define the cosine and sine from first principles and then in a [remark](https://drmenguin.com/files/trig.pdf#lemma.2) I discuss how the definitions are equivalent to the familiar power series $$\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k}{(2k)!}\,x^{2k}.$$

Comment: Yet the purely analytic definition of trigonometric functions (as exposed in Bourbaki, for instance) is via power series. In this case, one has to explain how they play a role in geometry.

Comment: @Bernard In the notes I linked, I _show_ that the geometric definition is equivalent to this (I do not start from this).

Comment: it's bizarre that at least at my university iv never seen sine defined properly, iv never seen the explanation of why the series definition agrees with the geometric one except maybe with complex numbers, but that's not quite it.  But I would like a purely geometric coordinate free definition if it is possible to do so, no matter how much overkill it would be no coordinate definition means anything to me

Comment: @ArcDDD Did you see the notes I linked?

Comment: Do you use coordinates in them?

Comment: I scrolled quickly, if they are coordinate less than I'll be happy to read them

Comment: @ArcDDD It is not bizarre at all that you have not seen $\sin$ or $\cos$ defined without coordinates, because modern geometry is all done in $\mathbb R^n$, so that's why I'd say that it is esoteric to try and define sine and cosine without coordinates. Fundamentally, sine and cosine are defined to be the coordinates of a point on the circle $x^2+y^2=1$ in the plane.

Comment: Esoteric? Lol, I didn't say it was bizzare I haen seen a coordinate free definition of sine, but they I haven seen any that relates both infinite series and geometry..

Comment: Why did u use that word esoteric makes no sense

Comment: You can find a relationship between the geometry and power series in the notes I linked.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one approach. First, using coordinates, define arc length $\theta $ on the unit circle as the limit of the sum of the length of inscribed chords. Prove that for any $0 \le \theta < \text { circumference of circle }$ there is exactly one $(x,y)$ on the unit circle such that the arc length from (1,0) to (x,y) is $\theta .$ Define $\sin \theta =y, \cos \theta=x.$ Then prove that $$\lim_{\theta \to 0}\frac {\sin \theta}{\theta}=1$$ and thence prove that the derivatives of $\sin \theta$ and $\cos \theta$ are $\cos \theta$  and $-\sin \theta$ respectively, from which it follows that the $\sin \theta$ function is a solution of $f''(\theta)+f(\theta)=0, f(\theta)=0,f'(\theta)=1.$. $$*$$ Second, define as power series $$\text {ssin}\theta=\theta-\frac{\theta^3}{3!}+\frac{\theta^5}{5!}-...$$ and $$\text {ccos}\theta=1-\frac{\theta^2}{2!}+\frac{\theta^4}{4!}-...$$ Thence prove that the derivatives of $\text { ssin } \theta \text { and } \text {ccos} \theta \text { are ccos }  \theta \text { and -ssin } \theta$ respectively,from which it follows that the $\text { ssin }\theta$ function is also a solution of $f''(\theta)+f(\theta)=0, f(\theta)=0,f'(\theta)=1.$. $$*$$ Third, prove that the solution of $f''(\theta)+f(\theta)=0, f(\theta)=0,f'(\theta)=1$ is unique. Thus the geometrically defined sine function equals its power series expansion. The same could and should be done for the cosine function.

Comment: I Sai without coordinates!!!???

Comment: @ArcDDD what's wrong with you... calm down

Comment: What's  wrong with you? I write specifically no coordinates first thing this guy does is "let's define coordinates? What is that??

Comment: I just wanted to show that the coordinate approach gives the same result as the power-series approach.

Comment: Why in the world did you feel the need to do so. I even stated in the description this is how it's done in those COORDICT  algorithms, I said I don't want that..

Comment: This is getting funny

Comment: Being illiterate is not funny

Comment: @ArcDDD Like how do you expect to define cosine without coordinates? The definition of cosine *is* the ratio between the adjacent side and hypotenuse, then you extend it for all real angles and eventually complex numbers... (Which is also equivalent to the unit circle definition).

Comment: I don't know how, if I knew I wouldn't ask