# How to derive the "geometric interpretation" of trig functions from their taylor series alone?

Tags: trigonometry, taylor-expansion

In trigonometry, we often define sine and cosine respectively to be the y and x coordinates given a ray coming of the origin that touches the unit circle. Later on using calculus we somehow arrive at their respective taylor series.

My question is what if we start defining sine and cosine function to be their respective taylor series or as limits of some taylor polynomial, how can we arrive to the fact that these functions indeed represent the y and x coordinates of a point in the unit circle given some angle?

Comment: From the series representations, you can show the Pythagorean theorem by differentiating, so you know that $(\cos(x), \sin(x))$ lies on the unit circle. I had to do this as part of a take home exam in analysis. Knowing this and $\cos(0)=1$, you should be able to use rotations to argue it.

Comment: See, for instance, [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2758743/409), which illustrates that (the absolute values of) the terms of the power series are lengths of successive involutes derived from a unit-circular arc. The involutes determine a polygonal spiral whose left-right and up-down displacements "converge" on segments representing the standard geometric definitions of cosine and sine. (A counterpart figure works for tangent and secant.)

Answer (score 5):

From the series alone, you can deduce that $\cos^2t+\sin^2t=1$ for all $t$. Therefore $(\cos t,\sin t)$ is a point on the unit circle.

From the series alone you can deduce that $\frac{d}{dt}\sin t=\cos t$ and $\frac{d}{dt}\cos t=-\sin t$. So the vector derivative of $(\cos t,\sin t)$ is $\langle-\sin t,\cos t\rangle$. Therefore it is always orthogonal to the position $(\cos t,\sin t)$ and has constant magnitude $1$.

So the path $(\cos t,\sin t)$ is tracing out a unit circle in the counter-clockwise direction moving at a constant speed. So at time $t$, the "angle" that has been covered is some linear function of $t$. It is simplest to scale the definition of "angle" in such a way as to make that function simply be $t$.