# How can the circular function $\tan(\theta)$ be both a length and a ratio of lengths?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

The circular function  $\tan(\theta)$ is defined as $\tan (\theta)=\frac{\sin (\theta)}{\cos (\theta)}$. If we look at this in the context of the Unit Circle:

[image: tan theta on the Unit Circle]

From this picture it can be seen that $\tan(\theta)$ is the $y$-coordinate of the $Q(1,y_1)$, the point on the terminal side of $\theta$ that lies on the vertical line $x=1$. So like $\sin(\theta)$ and $\cos(\theta)$ it signifies a length on the Unit Circle.

My question is: How can $\tan(\theta)$ be a length if it is a ratio of two lengths? The ratio of two lengths is dimensionless, so how does $\tan(\theta)$ signify a length?

EDIT: I guess this goes for $\sin(\theta)$ and $\cos(\theta)$ as well; as they are ratios of two lengths.

EDIT 2: mislabeled sine and cosine on the unit circle

Answer (score 7):

$\sin \theta$ and $\cos\theta$ are themselves dimensionless (since they're ratios of length) but their value represent the magnitude of a length in the unit circle.

Comment: Interesting, I overlooked this..

Answer (score 7):

Note that all quantities involved: $\theta$, $\cos\theta$, $\sin\theta$, and $\tan\theta$ are just real numbers. They appear as lengths only after you draw a picture: Length of a certain arc on the unit circle (whatever that means), lengths of certain segments in the plane.

It is the introduction of a coordinate system that make this possible: Marking the points $0$ and $1$ on each of the axes allows to interpret not only real numbers $x$, but also expressions like $x^2$, $x^3$, $e^x$, etc. for given $x\in{\mathbb R}$  as lengths. The ancient Greeks could view quantities like $a\cdot b$ or $x^2$ only as pieces of area.

Answer (score 4):

Both $\sin \theta$ and $\cos \theta$ as well as $\tan \theta$  are ratios of lengths and do not specify lengths in themselves. In your diagram, you have interchanged the places where $\sin \theta$ and $\cos \theta$ are written.

You are able to write the lengths of the base and height of the right triangle as $\cos \theta$ and $\sin \theta$ only because the length of the hypotenuse is taken to be $1$. Hence, don't confuse the ratios in general with the length.

Answer (score 3):

$\tan\theta$ is the vertical offset of the point relative to its horizontal offset (from the origin). In this respect, one can only considered $\tan\theta$ as a *length* if the horizontal offset is equal to 1 (which is in fact the case with the Unit Circle).

Answer (score 1):

I personally prefer this rendering of the trig segments:

[image]

(My avatar ---the logo of my company--- is based on it, and it's the inspiration for my iPhone app, [Trigger](http://tricochet.com/trigger/). My attachment to this figure is significant ... but I digress ...)

I look at this picture as *definitional*. To me, $\tan\theta$ is *defined* as the length of a segment that's tangent to the unit circle. (So, the name *makes sense!*) The ratio that most textbooks give as a(n entirely-unmotivated) definition is actually a *theorem*. It expresses a proportion based on the similarity of the $\tan\theta$-$1$-$\sec\theta$ and the $\sin\theta$-$\cos\theta$-$1$ right triangles in the figure:

$$\frac{\tan\theta}{1} = \frac{\sin\theta}{\cos\theta}$$

Likewise, similarity with other triangles gives these proportions
$$\frac{\tan\theta}{1} = \frac{1}{\cot\theta} \qquad\text{and}\qquad \frac{\tan\theta}{1} = \frac{\sec\theta}{\csc\theta}$$
but I think I'm digressing again. :)

In any case, we resolve the length-vs-ratio-of-lengths conflict by realizing that

> *Ratio* $\tan\theta$ represents *length* $\tan\theta$, over *length* $1$.
>
> Conversely, *length* $\tan\theta$ represents *length $1$*, scaled by *ratio* $\tan\theta$.

The same goes for $\sin\theta$, $\cos\theta$, and the rest. They're lengths, and they're ratios-of-lengths.

In practice, you'll rarely think of trig values as lengths, just as you rarely think of the product $xy$ in some formula as the area of an $x$-by-$y$ rectangle. Nevertheless, the duality can be instructive; *seeing* the trig functions as lengths in the figure above explains a great deal about their properties and relations.

I'll end with a pointer to [this answer of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1103/409) which describes how the *power series* for sine and cosine, and for tangent and secant, have geometric interpretations. Not only are the trig values presented at lengths, so is $\theta$ ---naturally, the length of a circular arc--- as well as *each power of $\theta$*, despite all of these things ostensibly being "dimensionless".

Answer (score 0):

All trigonometric functions like $sin\theta ,cos\theta ,tan\theta$ are dimensionless just like $\theta$.They are defined as lengths on the unit circle just the way 1 N(newton) is defined as force on 1 kg object moving at 1 m/s^2