# Proving the inequality $\sin{\theta} \leq \theta \leq \tan{\theta} $

Tags: calculus, limits, trigonometry, inequality

In the Squeeze Theorem proof of $\lim\limits_{\theta\to 0}\frac{\sin{\theta}}{\theta} $, the appeal is made to the [obvious triangle inclusion](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/75151/49487) in the image on the unit circle below to say that

$$\frac{\sin{\theta}}{2} \leq \frac{\theta}{2} \leq \frac{\tan{\theta}}{2} $$

While it is indeed obvious that these triangles share this inequality relationship, I was wondering how it can be rigorously proven.  For the purposes of answering, it's fine to prove it for just the upper right quadrant of the unit circle, i.e. when $0 < \theta < \frac{\pi}{2}$.

[image]

Comment: I mean, this *is* a rigorous proof

Comment: @AmejiB. : No, it's not. $\qquad$

Comment: You want a rigorous proof of Area($\triangle ABC$)$\,<\,$Area(blue sector)$\,<\,$Area($\triangle ABD$)? Is that what you're asking? That'd have to start with a rigorous definition of the concept of area. Things here can get pretty complicated.

Comment: @MichaelHardy What about it is not rigorous? I mean as bjorn points out, questions about area can get fundamentally messy, but you might as well be reinventing the wheel at that point

Comment: @AmejiB. : A logically rigorous proof is amenable to algorithmic validity checking.

Comment: You did not answer why this is not logically rigorous

Comment: @AmejiB. : Logical rigor is concerned with definitions and connectives of propositional logic and such things as the equvialence of $\lnot\exists x\cdots$ and $\forall x\,\lnot\cdots$ and so on.

Comment: See my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1536080/291201) for a slightly different take, based on the two assumptions 1) circular sectors are convex, 2) the perimeter of a convex closed curve is smaller than that of any other one enclosing it.

Comment: You have still not answered my question...

Comment: Thanks @dvix.  Do those two assumptions follow from particular axioms?

Comment: For a rigorous treatment of trigonometric functions we have to use Calculus, not Geometry.

Comment: @bgcode Those are basic properties that hold true in formalisms that define convexity and curve length. You don't say in the question *which* axioms you work with, or what you are willing to accept as "*rigorous*".

Comment: I see @dvix.  How about working from Euclid's axioms, or Hilbert's?  Or using set theory axioms from ZFC without geometry axioms at all, if that's possible.  I'm a math n00b, so I'm not sure which axioms I should assume to be working from.  For example, in my earlier geometry notes, I wrote that Corresponding Angles Axiom was: If a transversal intersects two parallel lines, then each pair of corresponding angles are congruent. Not sure if that's a Euclidean axiom or what..  But I'd like to know the axioms I could/should learn/work with for being rigorous as I learn calc.

Comment: @bgcode There is a long way from Euclid's axioms to rigorous definitions of both trig functions and geometric imagery (curves, convexity, arc length). You can find some pointers in related questions [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1048/different-definitions-of-trigonometric-functions), [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1176098/what-are-some-rigorous-definitions-for-sine-and-cosine), [3](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1303044/axiomatic-definition-of-sin-and-cos).

Comment: @dxiv So it seems like I need to either accept some higher level axioms, or wait until I understand a lot more math to build up from those axioms?  This is one of the first cases I've run into where something far from Euclid needed to be used as a geometric axiom, but maybe that's par for the course?  Also one idea that came to mind is if you had a function defining the area of the sector, could you maybe set up an inequality from that? Just an idea.  Any tips on how to approach rigor in general as I learn are welcome as well.  Thank you!

Comment: This follows from the Taylor series expansion of sine, since we need only check $\theta < 1$, and once you get the left-hand inequality, the right follows immediately.