# How to improve the small angle approximations for $\sin x$ and $\cos x$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, trigonometry, power-series, taylor-expansion

If we start with the approximation

$ \sin x \approx x$

we derive, using the trigonometric relation

$ 1 - \cos 2x = 2\sin^2x$

we get that $\cos x \approx 1 - \frac{x^2}{2} $

Is it possible to use this new approximation to improve the approximation for $\sin x$ in order to get more terms of the Taylor series expansion?

Using the same procedure, I found that

$\sin x \approx x -  \frac{x^3}{8} $

where the second term of the Taylor's expansion is

$\sin x \approx x -  \frac{x^3}{6} $.

How to get the correct next term using elementary trigonometric formulas?

Answer (score 2):

$\large\text{Picard's Iteration Process:}$

---

Step I:

See that

$$\sin(x)=\int_0^x\cos(t)dt\approx\int_0^x1-\frac{t^2}2dt=x-\frac{x^3}6$$

---

Step II:

Use step I and see that

$$\cos(x)=1-\int_0^x\sin(t)dt\approx1-\int_0^xt-\frac{t^3}6dt=1-\frac{x^2}2+\frac{x^4}{24}$$

---

Step III:

Then repeat step I using what you found in step II.

---

Step III:

Repeat step II using what you find in step III.

Etc.

Comment: Could you post the name of that method you used so that others can search for similar ideas?

Comment: @AlgorithmsX no idea what you would call it, but it works for repeating derivatives.

Comment: @AlgorithmsX It was from [this question of mine](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2005872/deriving-taylor-series-without-applying-taylors-theorem).

Comment: It's called a Picard Iteration Process. Here's a post of mine that discusses it for $\tan x$: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2020219/how-does-integrating-the-derivative-of-this-approximation-for-tangent-increase-i

Comment: Here's a link to that. http://www.sosmath.com/diffeq/first/picard/picard.html

Comment: @AlgorithmsX nice, I didn't know.

Comment: I would put it in your answer, as it can be near impossible to look up more stuff like this without a name or something to search for.

Comment: @SimpleArt This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @Bye_World Yeah, I decided to do that too in the other answer, albeit something I'd rather not do.

Comment: @SimpleArt Thanks for your answer. As I see, this iteration generates a series similar to the Taylor but with greather denominators. I was doubtful about if this series converges to the sine and cosine functions. Is the convergence guaranteed?

Comment: @FractionalInquirer I guarantee convergence for both my answer.  Notice that at first, there are greater denominators, though eventually those terms will add onto themselves and approach the values you would expect.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that

$$\cos(2x)=2\cos^2(x)-1$$

So, if $\cos(x)\approx1-\frac{x^2}2$, then

$$\cos(2x)\approx2\left(1-\frac{x^2}2\right)^2-1=1-2x^2+\frac{x^4}2$$

Then let $x\to\frac x2$ to get

$$\cos(x)\approx1-\frac{x^2}2+\frac{x^4}{32}$$

So, we repeat:

$$\cos(2x)=2\cos^2(x)-1\approx2\left(1-\frac{x^2}2+\frac{x^4}{32}\right)^2-1$$

etc., you get the idea.

---

Now that you have the expansion for cosine, we can use the other double angle identity:

$$\sin(2x)=2\sin(x)\cos(x)\approx2x\cos(x)=?$$

This step really depends on how you approximated your cosine, but the general result is the same.

Once you get a new approximation for $\sin(x)$, repeat the above formula over again, and again, etc.

---

$\large\text{Remark:}$ Notice we started with the so called **"small angle approximation"** and merely *doubled* the small angles to make a **"double-whatever-the-small-angle-was approximation"**.