# Are the definition of cosx got from power series and the triangle definition of cosx same?

Tags: trigonometry, power-series

[image]

For right angled triangle $ABC$,  $\cos x = \frac{adjacent}{hypotenuse} = \frac{AB}{BC}$

Again from power series expansion of $\cos x$ we get
$$\cos x = 1-\frac{x^{2}}{2!}+\frac{x^{4}}{4!}-\frac{x^{6}}{6!}+......$$
  Are these two definitions same?

Comment: Usually we don't allow triangles to have angles outside the range of $(0 \,\mathrm rad,\pi\,\mathrm{rad})$, or to have a negative base/hypotenuse. In that sense they're not the same since the power series is fine with any real $x$.

Comment: @MarkS. so we can say that the triangle definition is the limiting form of definition got from power series

Comment: There is another difference : In the first definition, $x$ is an angle (most written as $\alpha,\beta,etc.$, whereas in the second definition we have a function acting on real numbers (which only correspond to an angle). So you have to convert the angle into a number before you can use the second definition. For example $\sin(90°)$ has the same value as $\sin(\frac{\pi}{2})$

Comment: You can also extend the power series to complex values unlike the triangle definition.

Comment: The real puzzle is, "What is $x$ in the geometric sketch?" If we want to put that on a firm footing, we really do need to go down the power series route, as that will let us define $\pi$, lengths of circular arcs, and hence define angles. But the geometric sketches are good for our intuitions.

Comment: [This answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1103/409) may be helpful.