# How to memorize the families that are $\sin$, $\cos$, and $\tan$ of $\pi$ over something?

Tags: trigonometry, soft-question

Is there any way to easily memorize these? Such as $\sin \frac{\pi}{6} = 1/2$. Any help needed!!!

Answer (score 5):

Here's a nice trick:

$$
\sin\left(0\right) = \sqrt{\frac{0}{4}}\\
\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{6}\right) = \sqrt{\frac{1}{4}}\\
\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right) = \sqrt{\frac{2}{4}}\\
\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{3}\right) = \sqrt{\frac{3}{4}}\\
\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right) = \sqrt{\frac{4}{4}}
$$

where the angles are in increasing order.

Comment: This is pretty cool. :)

Comment: The same sort of trick works for $\cos$, but angles in decreasing order (in case that wasn't immediately clear for anyone).

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean $\pi/4$, $\pi/3$, $\pi/6$ and their multiples.

For sine and cosine, either draw a right triangle with the corresponding angle or draw a rough plot, remembering that there's a $\frac{1}{2}$ and $\frac{\sqrt 3}{2}$ somewhere. For tangent and cotangent just calculate the quotient.

Some others are easily calculated using trigonometric identities.

Answer (score 0):

I just remember that a 45-45-90 triangle is a square cut in half, and a 30-60-90 triangle is an equilateral triangle cut in half. Using the theorem of Pythagoras (which I memorized a long time ago) I can work out the side lengths. I also have to remember which is the sine and which is the cosine. My mnemonic for that is that for $(x,y)$ on the unit circle, $(x,y)=(\cos\theta,\sin\theta)$ where both sides of the equation are in alphabetical order. I find that a lot easier than using a vaguely racist mnemonic about an Indian Chief whose name I can never remember. OK, I think it's "Sohcahtoa" but my mnemonic for remembering "Sohcahtoa" is the trigonometric ratios.

Comment: What Indian Chef?

Answer (score 0):

**(1) Visualize it so you understand it** (and don't have to memorize it):

[google image search for pi/6](https://www.google.com/search?q=sin+pi/6&newwindow=1&rlz=1C1CHFX_enUS550US550&espv=210&es_sm=93&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=McbMUqPkN6qa2AWC0oHIDg&ved=0CAkQ_AUoAQ&biw=1092&bih=544#es_sm=93&espv=210&newwindow=1&q=sin%20pi/6&tbm=isch)

But it's also good to develop **"(2) skill of understanding"** by being able to quickly come up with the answer, like using flashcards, to make the understanding instinctual and fast.  And of course, **(3) applying the knowledge by solving problems**.  So you're neither "just memorizing facts" nor "just understanding and not doing the homework".  **It's the combination of (1) understanding, (2) "skill of understanding", and (3) problem solving that develops a good foundation for the mathematical mind.**

FYI, here's another good example of **"visualizing for memorizing"**: [Is there any intuition behind why the derivative of $\cos(x)$ is equal to $-\sin(x)$ or just something to memorize?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/78414/is-there-any-intuition-behind-why-the-derivative-of-cosx-is-equal-to-sin?rq=1)