# Is there a method to find the values given on the unit circle without drawing it out?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Is it possible to solve the sin/cos/tan of an angle and/or their inverses without a calculator, using the Taylor expansion, or looking at a unit circle? Recently I've just made myself memorize the unit circle and solved from there, but I know that can only take me so far.

Comment: No, not really. However one can get approximations to a desired accuracy using Taylor expansions (I know, you wanted to avoid this), and using the first order approximation will give you fairly good results just by knowing the value of a trig function at a nearby point.
$\sin(x) \approx \sin(x_0) + \cos(x_0) (\frac{x-x_0}{2\pi})$  
Where $x_0$ is a point nearby $x$ which you know the value of sine and cosine at. (note that you'll want to mod $x$ by $2 \pi$)

Comment: Please, if you are ok, you can accept the answer and set it as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that it suffice to memorize the important values in the first quadrant/octant and then obtain the others by symmetry and basic trigonometric identities.

See also:

[Easy way of memorizing values of sine, cosine, and tangent](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1553990/easy-way-of-memorizing-values-of-sine-cosine-and-tangent/1554126#1554126)

[How to memorize the families that are $\sin$, $\cos$, and $\tan$ of $\pi$ over something?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/628644/how-to-memorize-the-families-that-are-sin-cos-and-tan-of-pi-over-s)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should memorize the values (or use the unit circle) for a few common multiples of $\pi$ (denominators $1$, $2$, $3$, $4$ and $6$). After that you need a calculator or tables or Taylor series or other numerical methods.