# Deriving trigonometric derivatives in a purely geometric manner

Tags: geometry, derivatives

Is there any geometric way to derive basic trigonometric derivatives (without using the cos/sin of the sum formula)?

For example: $\dfrac d {dx}\cos x=-\sin x$

Comment: For sine and cosine, there's [this image in an answer to a similar question](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1093/409).