# Does there exist a tool to construct a perfect sine wave?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, recreational-mathematics, puzzle, geometric-construction

For example, a perfect circle can be constructed using a compass and a perfect ellipse can be constructed using two pins and a piece of string, because a circle can be defined as the locus of points equidistant from a circle point and an ellipse can be defined as the locus of all points such that the sum of the distances from that point to the two foci is constant.

[image]
I know that the sine function can be represented by the y-coordinate of an object in uniform circular motion, but does there exist a tool which allows you to draw a perfect sine wave (i.e. drawn by a human on paper)?

Comment: Humans can't draw anything perfectly.

Comment: Not quite what you want, but ... Take a transparent $2\pi \times 2\pi$ sheet, and draw one of its diagonals. Wrap the sheet around a clear cylinder of radius $1$. With an appropriately-placed light, the (now-helical) diagonal casts a shadow in the shape of a perfect sinusoid. (See [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1093/409) for a picture.)

Answer (score 23):

Take a circular cylinder and cut it by a plane not orthogonal to the axis.
As you roll the cylinder (without slipping) along the paper, the cut edge traces out a sine wave.

[image]

Comment: +1. Relatedly, you can wrap the cylinder in paper, make the cut as described above, and then unwrap: the paper will have a sinusoidal edge. (If you wrap the paper around more than once, the thickness of the paper will introduce imperfections that get worse and worse with each layer. A roll of paper towels, for instance, would be very bad for this kind of thing.)

Comment: A further question has been asked in http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1482727/a-further-question-to-does-there-exist-a-tool-to-construct-a-perfect-sine-wave . It is not asked in here because I cannot add a picture in the comment.

Comment: ***Sneaky !*** ;-$)$

Comment: I just stumbled upon this interesting constriction and have been trying to work on a proof; not sure if I should post this as a separate question but how can it be analytically proved that the graph is indeed sinusoidal?

Comment: To transfer the cut to paper, coat the cylinder near the cut with ink and roll it on the paper.

Answer (score 3):

Here's an ideal mechanical device to draw a sine curve: When a disk $D$ of radius $r$ (shaded below) rolls without slipping inside a circle $C$ of radius $2r$, each point on the perimeter of $D$ traces a diameter of $C$. Place such an apparatus over a roll of paper whose lateral speed (here, left to right) is constant (possibly geared to the angular speed with which $D$ rolls inside $C$, in order to control the wavelength). The boundary point of $D$ lying on the diameter of $C$ perpendicular to the lateral motion of the paper traces a sine curve on the paper.

[image: A rolling wheel traces a sine curve on a roll of paper]

Answer (score 0):

1. Make a small cart that rolls in a straight line.
2. To one of its wheels, attach a bevel gear (like the one below) which meshes with another whose axis is parallel to the motion of the cart, i.e. perpendicular to the front of the cart.
   [image]
3. To any point of the second gear except its middle, hang a laser so that it points downwards, and can freely swing like a gondola of a Ferris wheel. If larger amplitude is needed, add a crank and affix the laser to freely hang from it.
4. Slowly roll the cart over light-sensitive paper, ensuring that the laser doesn't pendulate.

The bevel gears convert horizontal motion into rotation perpendicular to direction of travel. The free-hanging laser extracts the second gear's horizontal component which is sinusoidal. The motion of the cart translates the paper uniformly relative to the cart to trace out the sine wave.