# Truncated Cylinder Projections and Development equation

Tags: algebraic-geometry, solid-geometry

Please, consider a simple truncated cylinder. There are many web sites where you can learn to draw [the projection or exploded view of the lateral side](http://etc.usf.edu/clipart/42500/42568/truncyl_42568.htm). It would be great if I could have the equation of the curve to feed a plotter in order to cut a sheet of the truncated cylinder. The parameters could be the radius of the cylinder and the angle of the intersecting plane. 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What have you done? Have you tried solving the system of equations $x^2+y^2=r^2, x=\alpha z$? Where do you get stuck?

Answer (score 0):

I have just found it. The answer is in ["Unwrapping Curves from Cylinders and Cones" by Tom Apostol](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/635c/920e5ee4651f0e3f48e02d74bdf4e98e6e8f.pdf). There is a cute example of a painting cylinder submerged at angle in the paint, the resulting pattern is a sine wave like $u(x)=h \space sin \frac{x}{r}$ where $r$ is the radius of the cylinder and $h=r \space tan(\beta)$ being $\beta$ the angle of the cutting plane. 
Also thanks to member [Robert Israel](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/8508/robert-israel) for his [response to an unrelated question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1482183/does-there-exist-a-tool-to-construct-a-perfect-sine-wave/1482203#1482203) (just see the animation)