# How does integrating trigonometric functions work?

Tags: sequences-and-series, trigonometry

I tried searching Google but all I get is what integrating each trigonometric function equals to.
Nothing tells me why.

I can sort of see why:

${d\over dx} \sin(x) = \cos(x)$

And...

${d\over dx} \cos(x) = -\sin(x)$

Purely by looking at the two graphs. But I want to know the maths behind it. How does integrating both functions work?
Why the results?

I've also seen from Wolfram Alpha that trigonometric functions can be written as series, but is there any article I can read that explains how these series are derived?
I can't seem to find any.

**UPDATE**: Wow. Thank you everyone for sharing your knowledge. You have no idea how much you've helped :).

Comment: do you know the series expansion $\sin, \cos$ etc.?

Comment: Consider googling for Proofs of the derivative of cosx and sinx as it might help make clear why the integrations work the way they do.

Comment: @math635 you need the notion of derivative to define series expansion...

Comment: @math635 - I've seen the series expansions for the trigonometric functions, but can't find articles on how they're derived.

Comment: @patrickh - I will do...I think my problem is, I'm just not good with Google haha. I never know what to type :(

Comment: Your title only mentions integrating, but the question itself expresses some doubt about differentiating. The answers to this question might help: ["Intuitive understanding of the derivatives of $\sin x$ and $\cos x$"](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/392/intuitive-understanding-of-the-derivatives-of-sin-x-and-cos-x).

Comment: A textbook on the Calculus should have explantations of these formulas.  Formulas for derivatives of trig functions.  Taylor series.  Other types of series.  But this is too broad to include in an answer here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$
\begin{split}
\frac{d [\sin x]}{dx}
 &= \lim_{h \to 0^+} \frac{\sin(x+h) - \sin x}{h} \\
 &= \lim_{h \to 0^+} \frac{\sin x \cos h + \cos x \sin h - \sin x}{h} \\
 &= \lim_{h \to 0^+} \frac{\sin x (\cos h - 1) + \cos x \sin h}{h} \\
 &= \sin x \left(\lim_{h \to 0^+} \frac{\cos h - 1}{h} \right)
  + \cos x \left( \lim_{h \to 0^+} \frac{\sin h}{h} \right)\\
 &= \sin x \cdot 0 + \cos x \cdot 1 \\
 &= \cos x.
\end{split}
$$

**UPDATE**
To finish this off you need a proof that
$$\lim_{h \to 0^+} \frac{\cos h - 1}{h} = 0 \quad \text{and} \quad
\lim_{h \to 0^+} \frac{\sin h}{h} = 1.$$

Here is a creative way to show the first limit assuming the second limit. Note that $$\lim_{h \to 0^+} \frac{\cos h -1}{h} \times \frac{\cos h +1}{h} = \lim_{h \to 0^+} \frac{\cos^2 h -1}{h} = \lim_{h \to 0^+} \frac{-\sin^2 h}{h^2} = -1.$$ Since $$\lim_{h \to 0^+} \frac{\cos h +1}{h} = +\infty$$ we must conclude that $$\lim_{h \to 0^+} \frac{\cos h -1}{h} = 0.$$

Now the only thing left is to show the second limit, which is a geometric proof to establish the inequality $$\cos h \le \frac{\sin h}{h} \le 1,$$ and then using the Squeezing Theorem. You can see the details, for example, [here](https://www.math.rutgers.edu/~greenfie/summer_135/verification_sine.html).

Comment: This is REALLY clear... more so than I would have hoped :) thank you.

Comment: Question... is (cos(h)-1)\h) undefined when h=0?... and isn't  (sin(h)/h) the same as (cos(h)-1)\h) when h=0?

Comment: You have to show that $(\cos h -1)/h \to 0$. The easiest way is with the half-angle cos formula combined with $\sin h/h$ \to 1$.

Comment: @MaxEchendu see update...

Answer (score 3):

I'll assume you're aware that $\frac d{dx} e^{bx} = be^{bx}$ where $b \in \Bbb R$.  It turns out that this also holds when $b$ is a complex number.  Using this and the definition of the trig functions [in terms of the exponential function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_functions#Relationship_to_exponential_function_and_complex_numbers) it's easy to see that

$$\begin{align}\frac d{dx}\cos(x) &= \frac d{dx}\left(\frac{e^{ix}+e^{-ix}}{2}\right) \\ &= \frac 12\left(\frac d{dx}e^{ix}+\frac d{dx}e^{-ix}\right) \\ &= \frac 12\left(ie^{ix}-ie^{-ix}\right) \\ &= \frac 12\left(\frac iiie^{ix}-\frac iiie^{-ix}\right) \\ &= -\frac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{2i}\ \\ &= -\sin(x)\end{align}$$

Comment: Oh now this looks good. Thank you so much :). Do you know any article I can look at regarding the series expansions of sine and cosine?

Comment: Any book on infinite series should cover that.

Comment: Alright thank you for your help :). Much appreciated.

Comment: Usually Euler's formula requires using the Taylor expansion of the sine and cosine functions to prove, which first requires knowing their derivatives, so isn't this cyclic? Can one show Euler's formula without knowing the trigonometric derivatives?

Comment: I'm simply defining $\sin$ and $\cos$ in terms of $\exp$.  Of course that's a bit of a cheat, but OP will learn more about this later anyway.

Answer (score 1):

The most important
limit formula for trig functions is
$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\sin h}{h}
= 1$.
You can convince yourself
of this by looking
at a triangle with angle $h$
in a circle of radius $1$.
The best way to show this
analytically is probably
to use the power series,
but the diagram of
the small angle in the circle
is where it all comes from.

Once you have this,
the formulas for
the derivatives of
the trig functions
readily follow.

Another result is that
$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\cos h - 1}{h}
= 0
$.
But this follows from 
the $\sin$ limit combined with
$\cos h - 1
=-2\sin^2(h/2)
$
so
$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\cos h - 1}{h}
=\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{-2\sin^2(h/2)}{h}
=\lim_{h \to 0} \sin(h/2)\frac{-\sin(h/2)}{h/2}
= 0
$
since the right term
goes to $-1$
and the left term
goes to zero.

Comment: That helped clear things up. Thank you :).