# help needed to compute derivative of $e^{x\sin x}$

Tags: trigonometry, logarithms, exponential-function

How should I compute the derivative of $e^{x\sin x}$ ?
I am a student of class 11, so can you explain me how to do this without high level mathematics ( I know first principles )
I know that derivative of $e^x$ is $e^x$, but I cannot understand what to do with that $\sin x$?

Comment: Use the chain rule for differentiation. $e^{ x \sin x } = f ( g ( x ) )$. Let $f(x) = e^x$ and let $g(x) = x \sin x$.

$f(g(x))' = f'(g(x)) g'(x)$

Comment: @user5183360  Derivative of $xsinx$ is $sinx+xcosx$ and so it($d/dx(e^{xsinx}$)) becomes $(sinx+xcosx)e^{xsinx}$

Comment: @user41736 Why is the nationality relevant? Is it necessary to identify what "class 11" means?

Answer (score 2):

Remind the chain rule
$$(f(g(x)))'=g'(x)f'(g(x))$$
and product rule:
$$(f(x)g(x))'=f'(x)g(x)+f(x)g'(x)$$
You can use follwing formulas:
$$
(e^x)'=e^x\text{ (you already know)}\\
(\sin x)'=\cos x\\
(x\sin x)'=\sin x + x\cos x
$$
and so
$$
(e^{x\sin x})'=(\sin x+x\cos x)e^{x\sin x}.
$$
[Intuitive understanding of the derivatives of $\sin x$ and $\cos x$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/392/intuitive-understanding-of-the-derivatives-of-sin-x-and-cos-x) may help you.

Answer (score 2):

$y=e^{x\cdot sinx}$, let $u=x\cdot sinx$

$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{dy}{du}\cdot \frac{du}{dx}$ (chain rule)

$\frac{dy}{du}=e^u$

$\frac{du}{dx}=x\cdot cosx + 1\cdot sinx$ (product rule)

$y'=e^u\cdot (x\cdot cosx+sinx)$

therefore: $y'=e^{xsinx}(x\cdot cosx+sinx)$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

Logarithmic differentiation is very useful $$y=e^{x\sin( x)}$$ Take logarithms $$\log(y)=x \sin(x)$$ Differentiate $$\frac{y'}y=x \cos(x)+\sin(x)$$ So $$y'=\big(x \cos(x)+\sin(x)\big)e^{x\sin x}$$

Comment: I'm not sure if this method is a really good one since it's applicable in this specific situation only !

Comment: @Surb. I am not sure I understand your point. As long as you can take logarithms, the method applies. It is, to me, the easiest way to explain the derivative of a product or a quotient.

Comment: Take $y=cosh(x)$, then $\ln(y)=\ln(\cosh(x))$ and thus $\frac{y'}{y}=\frac{d}{dx}(\ln(\cosh(x))$, and we arrive at the same problem than the beginning, i.e. to derivate a composition.

Comment: @Surb. I was speaking only about products and quotients.

Answer (score 0):

it is the chain and the power rule:
$${e^{x\sin(x)}}'=e^{x\sin(x)}(\sin(x)+x\cos(x))$$