# Why is the derivative of sine function is only cosine function?

Tags: calculus

Is there any other way to prove it rather than proving it using the formula by definition ?

Comment: "...rather that... **what**?

Comment: Related (duplicate?): [Intuitive understanding of the derivatives of $\sin x$ and $\cos x$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/392/409)

Comment: $\;(\sin x)'=\cos\;$ for any $\;x\in\Bbb R\;$ (in radians!) because that's what we get when we calculate the limit that defines the derivative of $\;\sin x\;$ ...what else?

Answer (score 0):

I'll present an "algebraic" proof of why the derivative of $\sin x$ in indeed "only $\cos x$." There are of course other, more geometric explanations that are more insightful as to why this intuitively makes sense.

By the definition of a derivative,
    \begin{equation*}
    \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d} x}  \sin (x) = \lim\limits_{h \to 0} \frac{\sin (x+h) - \sin x}{h}.
\end{equation*}
    Applying the trigonometric identity $\sin (a \pm b) = \sin a \cos b \pm \sin b \cos a$ gives us
    \begin{align*}
    \lim\limits_{h \to 0} \frac{\sin (x+h) - \sin x}{h} &= \lim\limits_{h \to 0} \frac{\sin x \cos h + \sin h \cos x -\sin x}{h} \\
    &= \lim\limits_{h \to 0} \frac{\sin x (\cos h  - 1) + \sin h \cos x}{h} \\
    &= \lim\limits_{h \to 0} \frac{\sin x (\cos h  - 1)}{h} + \lim\limits_{h \to 0} \frac{\sin h \cos x}{h}.
\end{align*}
    Note that $\sin x$ and $\cos x$ are constant when we evaluate the derivative, so
    \begin{equation*}
\lim\limits_{h \to 0} \frac{\sin x (\cos h  - 1)}{h} + \lim\limits_{h \to 0} \frac{\sin h \cos x}{h} =  \sin x \left(\lim\limits_{h \to 0} \frac{(\cos h  - 1)}{h}\right) + \cos x \left(\lim\limits_{h \to 0} \frac{\sin h}{h}\right).
\end{equation*}
    We can see that $\lim\limits_{h \to 0} \frac{(\cos h  - 1)}{h}$ converges to $0$ and $\lim\limits_{h \to 0} \frac{\sin h}{h}$ converges to $1$. Applying these results to the previous equations gives us
    \begin{equation*}
    \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d} x} \sin (x) = (\sin x)(0) + (\cos x)(1) = \cos x.
\end{equation*}

Note that similar logic can be used to derive the derivative of $\cos x$. These two results can then be used to derive the derivatives of other trigonometric functions such as $\tan x$ or $\csc x$.

Comment: The OP asked for a proof that is not "proving it using the formula by definition". While I admit that I have no idea what it means, it surely asks for something that is not your (otherwise excellent) answer, since you used a formula and a definition.

Comment: But what can we conclude from this proof i mean what is the hidden answer or logic of two lines to explain that cos is the only derivative of sine ?

Comment: @JaveriaZun the answers to the [related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/392/intuitive-understanding-of-the-derivatives-of-sin-x-and-cos-x) linked above provided a few geometric arguments for the relationship between the derivatives of $\sin$ and $\cos$. Are these of any help?

Comment: @Brian S yes these are very helpful but i just want a simple logical answer in words ....i mean by seeing this proof what is the answer that comes to our mind that this is the logic behind this answer ?